# How to hold an exception in an IObservable pipeline and re-throw it at the end?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following method:

```
public IObservable<DataManagementWorkItem> GetWorkItemSource(int maxConcurrentCalls)
{
    return m_namespaceManager
        .GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource(true, drainAndDisable: false)
        .Select(nci => Observable.Defer(() => GetPolicySourceForNamespace(nci)))
        .Merge(maxConcurrentCalls)
        .Where(IsValid)
        .Select(ToWorkItem)
        .Where(o => o != null);
}
```

It implements the following logic:

1. Enter the monad by obtaining `IObservable<NamespaceConnectionInfo>` from the namespace manager (`GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource`).
2. As namespaces become available obtain `IObservable<DataManagementPolicy>` corresponding to the particular namespace (`GetPolicySourceForNamespace`). However, use the `Merge` operator to restrict the number of concurrent calls to `GetPolicySourceForNamespace`.
3. Filter out bad `DataManagementPolicy` records (cannot be done in SQL).
4. Translate the seemingly good `DataManagementPolicy` records to `DataManagementWorkItem` instances. Some could turn out as `null`, so they are filtered out at the end.

The `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource` can fault after having produced certain amount of valid `NamespaceConnectionInfo` objects. It is entirely possible that certain amount of `DataManagementWorkItem` objects have already been produced by that time in the final observable sequence.

I have a unit test, where:

- `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource` throws after having produced 25 namespaces
- `GetPolicySourceForNamespace` produces 10 objects per namespace
- The concurrency limit is 10

I am also interested to examine the items produced in the final observable before it is faulted:

```
var dm = DependencyResolver.Instance.GetInstance<IDataManagement>();
var workItems = new List<DataManagementWorkItem>();
try
{
    var obs = dm.GetWorkItemSource(10);
    obs.Subscribe(wi => workItems.Add(wi));
    await obs;
    Assert.Fail("An expected exception was not thrown");
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    AssertTheRightException(exc);
}
```

The `workItems` collection has a different number of items every time. One run it has 69 items, another - 50, yet another - 18.

My interpretation is that when the fault occurs there are good `NamespaceConnectionInfo` and `DataManagementPolicy` objects in various phases of processing, all of which get aborted because of the fault. The amount is different each time, because the items are produced asynchronously.

And here lies my problem - I do not want them to be aborted. I want them to run to completion, be produced in the final observable sequence and only then to communicate the fault. In essence I want to hold the exception and re-throw it at the end.

I tried to modify the implementation a little bit:

```
public IObservable<DataManagementWorkItem> GetWorkItemSource(int maxConcurrentCalls)
{
    Exception fault = null;
    return m_namespaceManager
        .GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource(true, drainAndDisable: false)
        .Catch<NamespaceConnectionInfo, Exception>(exc =>
        {
            fault = exc;
            return Observable.Empty<NamespaceConnectionInfo>();
        })
        .Select(nci => Observable.Defer(() => GetPolicySourceForNamespace(nci)))
        .Merge(maxConcurrentCalls)
        .Where(IsValid)
        .Select(ToWorkItem)
        .Where(o => o != null)
        .Finally(() =>
        {
            if (fault != null)
            {
                throw fault;
            }
        });
}
```

Needless to say - it did not work. `Finally` does not seem to propagate any exceptions, which I actually agree with.

So, what is the right way to achieve what I want?

**EDIT**

Unrelated to the question, I have found that the test code I use to collect the produced `DataManagementWorkItem` instances is bad. Instead of

```
    var obs = dm.GetWorkItemSource(10);
    obs.Subscribe(wi => workItems.Add(wi));
    await obs;
```

it should be

```
    await dm.GetWorkItemSource(1).Do(wi => workItems.Add(wi));
```

The difference is that the latter subscribes to the source of items just once, whereas the original version subscribed twice:

1. by`Subscribe`
2. by `await`

It does not affect the qustion, but screws my mocking code.

**Clarification**

This more of a clarification. Each namespace produce a sequence of 10 policy objects. But this process is asynchronous - the policy objects are produced sequentially, but asynchronously. During all that time namespaces continue to be produced and hence given 25 namespaces before the fault there are three possible "states" in which a produced namespace can be:

- No policy objects have yet been produced for it, but the asynchronous policy production process has been started
- Some (but less that 10) policy objects have already been produced
- All 10 policy objects for the namespace have been produced

When an error in the namespace production occurs the entire pipeline is aborted, regardless of the "state" in which "good" namespaces are right now.

Let us have a look at the following trivial example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading;

namespace observables
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int count = 0;
            var obs = Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
                .Take(50)
                .Select(i =>
                {
                    if (25 == Interlocked.Increment(ref count))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Boom!");
                    }
                    return i;
                })
                .Select(i => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).Take(10).Select(j => i * 1000 + j)))
                .Merge(10);

            var items = new HashSet<long>();
            try
            {
                obs.Do(i => items.Add(i)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(items.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it I usually have the following output:

```
Boom!
192
```

But, it could also display 191. However, if we apply the fault concat solution (even if it does not work when there are no faults):

```
        int count = 0;
        var fault = new Subject<long>();
        var obs = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
            .Take(50)
            .Select(i =>
            {
                if (25 == Interlocked.Increment(ref count))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Boom!");
                }
                return i;
            })
            .Catch<long, Exception>(exc =>
            {
                fault.OnError(exc);
                return Observable.Empty<long>();
            })
            .Select(i => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).Take(10).Select(j => i * 1000 + j)))
            .Merge(10)
            .Concat(fault);
```

Then the output is consistently 240, because we let all the asynchronous processes that have already been started to complete.

**An awkward solution based on answer by pmccloghrylaing**

```
    public IObservable<DataManagementWorkItem> GetWorkItemSource(int maxConcurrentCalls)
    {
        var fault = new Subject<DataManagementWorkItem>();
        bool faulted = false;
        return m_namespaceManager
            .GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource(true, drainAndDisable: false)
            .Catch<NamespaceConnectionInfo, Exception>(exc =>
            {
                faulted = true;
                return Observable.Throw<NamespaceConnectionInfo>(exc);
            })
            .Finally(() =>
            {
                if (!faulted)
                {
                    fault.OnCompleted();
                }
            })
            .Catch<NamespaceConnectionInfo, Exception>(exc =>
            {
                fault.OnError(exc);
                return Observable.Empty<NamespaceConnectionInfo>();
            })
            .Select(nci => Observable.Defer(() => GetPolicySourceForNamespace(nci)))
            .Merge(maxConcurrentCalls)
            .Where(IsValid)
            .Select(ToWorkItem)
            .Where(o => o != null)
            .Concat(fault);
    }
```

It works both when the namespace production faults and both when it is successful, but it looks so awkward. Plus multiple subscriptions still share the fault. There must be a more elegant solution.

**GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource source code**

```
public IObservable<NamespaceConnectionInfo> GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource(bool? isActive = null,
    bool? isWorkflowEnabled = null, bool? isScheduleEnabled = null, bool? drainAndDisable = null,
    IEnumerable<string> nsList = null, string @where = null, IList<SqlParameter> whereParameters = null)
{
    IList<SqlParameter> parameters;
    var sql = GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSqls.GetSql(isActive,
        isWorkflowEnabled, isScheduleEnabled, drainAndDisable, nsList, @where, whereParameters, out parameters);
    var sqlUtil = m_sqlUtilProvider.Get(m_siteSettings.ControlDatabaseConnString);
    return sqlUtil.GetSource(typeof(NamespaceConnectionInfo), sqlUtil.GetReaderAsync(sql, parameters)).Cast<NamespaceConnectionInfo>();
}

public IObservable<DbDataReader> GetReaderAsync(string query, IList<SqlParameter> parameters = null, CommandBehavior commandBehavior = CommandBehavior.Default)
{
    return Observable.FromAsync(async () =>
    {
        SqlCommand command = null;
        try
        {
            var conn = await GetConnectionAsync();
            command = GetCommand(conn, query, parameters);
            return (DbDataReader)await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(commandBehavior | CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
        finally
        {
            DisposeSilently(command);
        }
    });
}

public IObservable<object> GetSource(Type objectType, IObservable<DbDataReader> readerTask)
{
    return Observable.Create<object>(async (obs, ct) => await PopulateSource(objectType, await readerTask, true, obs, ct));
}

private static async Task PopulateSource(Type objectType, DbDataReader reader, bool disposeReader, IObserver<object> obs, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        if (IsPrimitiveDataType(objectType))
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync(ct))
            {
                obs.OnNext(reader[0]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Get all the properties in our Object
            var typeReflector = objectType.GetTypeReflector(TypeReflectorCreationStrategy.PREPARE_DATA_RECORD_CONSTRUCTOR);

            // For each property get the data from the reader to the object
            while (await reader.ReadAsync(ct))
            {
                obs.OnNext(typeReflector.DataRecordConstructor == null ?
                    ReadNextObject(typeReflector, reader) :
                    typeReflector.DataRecordConstructor(reader));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (disposeReader)
        {
            reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second implementation has a flaw that you need to use `.Create(...)` to avoid. If you get multiple subscriptions to the returned observable then the `fault` may already have a value and your code will falsely report failure. You need to wrap the contents of the method in a `.Create(...)` to avoid this.

Comment: I do not think there is a problem. Although, I do not mention it in the post, the observable of namespaces is a cold observable, so multiple subscribers are isolated from each other and do not see each other's faults.

Comment: It's because you can have multiple subscribers to the return observable that they share the same `fault` variable. It has nothing to do with being hot or cold.

Comment: Oh, that. Now I see. Since my second implementation is plain wrong, I suppose your comment applies to the solution proposed by pmccloghrylaing, which uses a similar pattern. You are right, thanks again.

Comment: Are you expecting 100 results from your unit test?

Comment: 250. An exception is thrown when the namespace #25 is encountered, meaning we have already seen namespaces 0,1,...24 - 25 in total (I have just edited the post, it said 24 total). Each namespace produces 10 policy objects, hence I expect to see 250 items in the final observable sequence before it is faulted.

Comment: @mark - I appreciate all of your edits, and I can see that you get more processing, but you are kludging the solution. I'm trying to let you know that there is a clean Rx way of solving this problem. and that's by changing the way `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource` works. Can you please post the code for it?

Comment: @Enigmativity - here you go. `GetReaderAsync` returns an `IObservable`. This is a recent change, hence the names still suggest the return type of  `Task`.

Comment: @mark - Again I appreciate you posting further detail. I have to say that the the code associated with `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource` is very complicated. You're switching in and out of TPL, async/await, and Rx in a number of places. It's just overly complicated. You really need to stick to a simple, single query to pull your data. The `Observable.Using` operator is essential for doing this kind of work. You should be using that and avoiding all the TPL, async/await stuff. But this is definitely where you need to focus your attention on. If you simplify I think you can avoid the exception.

Comment: If I created an impression that there was always an exception, that is my fault. An exception **may** occur. It does not mean it always occurs. And an exception may occur because we are talking with a remote SQL database. It does not happen all the time, of course, but when it does my code has to behave properly. I am sorry, I do not think the code is overly complicated, it just iterates the SQL reader and publishes the items into an observable sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `m_namespaceManager.GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource(true, drainAndDisable: false)` returns an `IObservable<NamespaceConnectionInfo>`. Now, the contract for any single observable is this:

```
OnNext*(OnError|OnCompleted)
```

This means that you get zero or more values followed by one, and only one, of either an error or a completion.

You cannot get multiple errors from a single observable and you cannot get values after you have gotten an error.

If your observable does return more than one error it is breaking the normal Rx contract.

So, given this, it is impossible for you, given the existing code, to delay errors until the end of the observable because an error **is** the end of the observable.

What you can do is change the way that you produce your values in `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource` so that it generates multiple sequences calls `.Materialize()` before merging them back as one. This means that you would have a single `IObservable<Notification<NamespaceConnectionInfo>>` and that can have multiple errors and completions throughout the stream. You can then group this stream and handle the values before you handle the errors. But it all hinges on a change to `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource`, and since you haven't posted the source for this I cannot give you the right code.

To help understand this, look at this code:

```
var xs = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5 }.ToObservable();

xs
    .Select(x =>
    {
        if (x == 0)
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        else
            return x;
    })
    .Subscribe(
        x => Console.WriteLine(x),
        ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()));
```

It produces this:

```
1
2
3
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at UserQuery.<Main>b__0(Int32 x) in query_ioaahp.cs:line 45
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2._.OnNext(TSource value)
```

The values `4` & `5` simply do not get produced.

Now look at this code:

```
xs
    .Select(x =>
        Observable
            .Start(() =>
            {
                if (x == 0)
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                else
                    return x;
            })
            .Materialize())
    .Merge()
    .Where(x => x.Kind != NotificationKind.OnCompleted)
    .Subscribe(
        x => Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
            "{0} {1}",
            x.Kind,
            x.HasValue ? x.Value.ToString() : "")),
        ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()));
```

This produces the following:

```
OnNext 1
OnNext 4
OnError 
OnError 
OnNext 5
OnNext 3
OnNext 2
```

It's out of order because of the introduced parallelism.

But now you can handle all of the errors.

Comment: The `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource` produces **a single error**. No breach of contract here. And I do not see why cannot I delay errors until the end. pmccloghrylaing has clearly shown it is possible (the solution is incomplete, but the direction is promising).

Comment: @mark - But when i produces a single error is **has to be at the end** - that's the contract. So there aren't "errors" to delay til the end. There is a single error **at the end** already. pmccloghrylaing has simply taken the **error at the end** and **appended it to the end** - in other words his solution hasn't done anything useful at all. Can you explain to me if I've misunderstood anything here?

Comment: I have edited my post - added a clarification. Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Would `Concat` solve your problem? I've wrapped it in `Observable.Create` with `Finally` to complete the `faults` subject.

```
public IObservable<DataManagementWorkItem> GetWorkItemSource(int maxConcurrentCalls)
{
    return Observable.Create<DataManagementWorkItem>((observer) =>
    {
        var faults = new Subject<DataManagementWorkItem>();
        return m_namespaceManager
            .GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource(true, drainAndDisable: false)
            .Catch<NamespaceConnectionInfo, Exception>(exc =>
            {
                faults.OnError(exc);
                return Observable.Empty<NamespaceConnectionInfo>();
            })
            .Take(maxConcurrentCalls)
            .Select(nci => GetPolicySourceForNamespace(nci))
            .Merge()
            .Where(IsValid)
            .Select(ToWorkItem)
            .Where(o => o != null)
            .Finally(() => faults.OnCompleted())
            .Concat(faults)
            .Subscribe(observer);
    });
}
```

Also, does this return what you expect? (24 in your test)

```
m_namespaceManager
    .GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource(true, drainAndDisable: false)
    .Catch<NamespaceConnectionInfo, Exception>(exc =>
    {
        faults.OnError(exc);
        return Observable.Empty<NamespaceConnectionInfo>();
    })
    .Count()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the proposed solution has a problem. When there is no fault the `faults` never completes, hence the resulting sequence never completes.

Comment: Another problem, spotted by Enigmativity, is that multiple subscribers are going to share the same `faults` subject. So, if one subscriber faults out, then others are likely to be affected, even if they did not have any errors.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. When `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource` has an error it stops producing values - the `.Catch` turns the error into an `OnComplete` (as it replaces the error with an empty obversable). So the source has completed and then the `.Concat` comes in to place and pops the exception back on the end of the observable - right where it was before. This doesn't allow the original source to run past the exception at all.

Comment: That seems strange. The faults shouldn't be added until all of the merged observables have completed.

Comment: @pmccloghrylaing - That's correct, but the errors are coming from `GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource` and not `GetPolicySourceForNamespace` so it doesn't make a difference to the final result. In this query the select involving `GetPolicySourceForNamespace` is just noise to the underlying issue.

Comment: You probably also need to use a `ReplaySubject` as the subject would be subscribed to after the value is added.

Comment: @pmccloghrylaing - I have edited the post, it sees 25 namespaces before faulting. Yes, the `Count()` would be 25.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the basic problem is the `Merge` has a fail fast implementation.  If the source observable produces an error, or any of the inner observables produce an error, then `Merge` fails the stream without waiting for the remaining inner observables to finish.

To achieve what you want, you need to "catch" the error before merge sees it, and "rethrow" it after the inner observables have finished:

```
public IObservable<DataManagementWorkItem> GetWorkItemSource(int maxConcurrentCalls)
{
    // wrap within Observable.Defer
    // so that each new subscription
    // gets its own Error subject
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        var error = new ReplaySubject<DataManagementWorkItem>(1);

        return m_namespaceManager
            .GetNamespaceConnectionInfoSource(true, drainAndDisable: false)
            .Catch(err =>
            {
                error.OnError(err);
                return Observable.Empty<NamespaceConnectionInfo>();
            })
            .Finally(error.OnCompleted)
            .Select(nci => Observable.Defer(() => GetPolicySourceForNamespace(nci)))
            .Merge(maxConcurrentCalls)
            .Where(IsValid)
            .Select(ToWorkItem)
            .Where(o => o != null)
            .Concat(error);
    });
}
```

Also, I note your unit test is subscribing *twice* to the returned observable, which is adding to your confusion.  Once with a call to `Subscribe` to populate your list, and again with `await`.  You really only want to subscribe once.  We can use the `.Do` operator to populate your list and you should be able to inspect it within your error handler:

```
var dm = DependencyResolver.Instance.GetInstance<IDataManagement>();
var workItems = new List<DataManagementWorkItem>();
try
{
    var obs = dm.GetWorkItemSource(10).Do(workItems.Add);
    await obs;
    Assert.Fail("An expected exception was not thrown");
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    AssertTheRightException(exc);
    // workItems should be populated.
}
```